# JS - Set visibility of a div to hidden via a button

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

```js
function button1() {
    document.getElementById("id1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.d1 {
    font-family: "Aldrich";
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="d1" id ="id1">Test</div>

<button onclick="button1">Button 1</button>
```

I use the above simple code to set the `visibility` of a `div` to `hidden` via a `button`. I click on it but nothing happens. If I set the property `visibility: hidden;` directly to `d1` it does work though...

Comment: You just forgot the parentheses: **onclick="button1"** becomes **onclick="button1()"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function button1() {
  document.getElementById("id1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.d1 {
    font-family: "Aldrich";
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1" id ="id1">Test</div>

<button onclick="button1()">Button 1</button>
```

You forgot to call the method from button click.
For calling a method `button1()`

Answer (score 2):

missing the `button1()` on your html `<button>`

```js
function button1() {
    document.getElementById("id1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.d1 {
    font-family: "Aldrich";
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1" id ="id1">Test</div>

<button onclick="button1()">Button 1</button>
```